# Gulp watch: Conditionally run tasks dependent on event.type

Tags: javascript, gulp, watch

I've got the following:

```
gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['compile']);
gulp.watch('src/**/*', (event) => {
  if (event.type === 'deleted' {
    gulp.src(event.path.replace('src/', 'compiled/')).pipe(clean());
  } else {
    // TODO: Only run 'compile' when file is not deleted.
  }
});
```

Whenever a file is added or modified I would like to run the `compile` task which will take the new file and move it into the compiled directory.

Whenever a file is deleted I do not want to run the `compile` task as it will do nothing. Instead, I need to remove the file from the compiled directory.

The above code works, but continues to run the compile task (resulting in a no-op) when a file is deleted.

How can I conditionally run another task? It looks like both the `run` and `start` Gulp methods have been removed and/or deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can include {read: false} in your task which should work

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/tmp', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
```

Comment: ?? I don't understand why that is relevant?

Comment: By setting read: false you are basically telling gulp to ignore the file(s) deleted
if (event.type === 'deleted' {
    gulp.src(event.path.replace('src/', 'compiled/', {read: false})).pipe(clean());
  }